# how to position a list of columns in the right side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem that sometimes `.col-sm-8` has not enough elements and the `.col-sm-4` falling to the left. `col-sm-4` columns are like sidebar and the content `col-sm-8` same time may be empty. 
How to position them as in the picture and still be able to use bootstrap column magic on resize?

Unfortunately I can not use row as the divs order are:

```
<div class='col-sm-4'>
<div class='col-sm-8'>
<div class='col-sm-4'>
<div class='col-sm-4'>
```

Because on mobile I need to reorder them with that way.
[image]

Comment: Did you get a chance to take a look at my code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Solution was easy than I thought:

```
.col-sm-8 { min-height: 100vh; }
```

It fixing the bug that that `col-sm-4` always falling left if `col-sm-8` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Run the code snippet full page to see the 8 to 4 layout.

```css
.border {
    border: .125em solid;
    height: 200px;
}

.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right border">SM 4</div>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-8 border'>SM 8</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-sm-8 invisible"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 border">SM 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-sm-8 invisible"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 border">SM 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's definitely create the right structure.
But unfortunately if `.col-sm-8` is longer than shown in the picture everything falls apart.

Comment: What do you mean by if it is longer?

Comment: for example if `sm-8` will have a lot of content and the height of the column will be longer then the `sm-4` columns